I cannot hide the "New" button in SharePoint list using JSON
I have tried using the following JSON code to hide the "new" button from SharePoint list but it has no effect. It works on all other buttons except new. Can some please help?
Here is the JSON:
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/row-formatting.schema.json",
  "commandBarProps": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "key": "new",
        "hide": true
        
      },
      {
        "key": "New",
        "text": "Fred",
        "iconname": "Fred"
      },
      {
        "key": "share",
        "hide": true
      },
      {
        "key": "edit",
        "hide": true
      },
      {
        "key": "automate",
        "hide": true
      },
      {
        "key": "alertMe",
        "hide": true
      },
      {
        "key": "integrate",
        "hide": true
      },
      {
        "key": "manageAlert",
        "hide": true
      }
    ]
  }
}


Why are you using new and New key 2 times in your JSON?

I agree with Ganesh Sanap. I am checking the status of this case. Please let us know if you would like further assistance.
If you have any update about this issue, please feel free to post back.

I just tried using below JSON in SharePoint list view formatting and it works fine for me:
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/row-formatting.schema.json",
  "commandBarProps": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "key": "new",
        "hide": true
      }
    ]
  }
}

Output:

Note: New button will not be hidden from all views by default. It will be hidden only from the list view where you have applied the JSON.
Documentation: SharePoint JSON formatting - Command bar customization syntax reference.
